# Guardar multiples imagenes y archivos en una tabla - codeigniter 4

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Estoy tratando de guardar varias imagenes  y varios archivos en mi tabla proyectos, compuesta por:

> id, id_empresa, nombre_proyecto, img, archivos, facturas, fecha

Funciona del siguiente modo:

> **si solo subo facturas-> no aparece nada (debería subir los archivos)**

> si solo subo fotos-> se crean correctamente (esto es correcto)

> si no subo nada -> me indica que no hay archivos (esto es correcto)

> Si comento la condición de subir imagenes y los datos referidos a
> imagenes y dejo solo facturas -> se suben los archivos adecuandamente

Adjunto imagen de la función de guardar:

```
public function guardar(){

    helper(['text','form', 'url']);

    $proyectos = new ProyectosModel();
 
    $validacion = $this->validate([
        'nombre_proyecto' => 'required|min_length[3]',
        'id_empresa' => 'required'
    ]);


     $validacionIMG = $this->validate([
        'img' => [
            'uploaded[img]',
            'mime_in[img,image/jpg,image/png,image/jpeg]',
            'max_size[img,1024]'
        ]
    ]); 

    $validacionFacturas = $this->validate([
        'facturas' => [
            'uploaded[facturas]',
            'mime_in[facturas,application/pdf]',
            'max_size[facturas,4096]'
        ]
    ]);

        $nombreRandom = random_string('numeric', 6);
        $nombreRandomFactura = random_string('numeric', 6);

        if (!$validacion){

            $session = session();
            $session->setFlashdata('mensaje','Por favor, revise la información');
            return redirect()->back()->withInput();
        }elseif($validacion && !$validacionIMG && !$validacionFacturas){
            $data = [
                'nombre_proyecto'=> $this->request->getVar('nombre_proyecto'),
                'id_empresa'=> $this->request->getVar('id_empresa')
             ];
            $proyectos->insert($data);
        }elseif($validacion && $validacionIMG != null && !$validacionFacturas){
        $nombreRandom = random_string('numeric', 6);

        if ($this->request->getFileMultiple('img')) {
            $imagenes = [];
            foreach($this->request->getFileMultiple('img') as $file)
            {   
               $nuevoNombre = $nombreRandom . '-' . $file->getName();
               $file->move('./public/assets/img',$nuevoNombre);
               $imagenes[] = $nuevoNombre;
            }
            $data = [
               'nombre_proyecto'=> $this->request->getVar('nombre_proyecto'),
               'id_empresa'=> $this->request->getVar('id_empresa'),
               'img' =>  implode(",",$imagenes)
            ];
        
       }

       $proyectos->insert($data);
       } elseif($validacion && $validacionFacturas != null && !$validacionIMG){
        $nombreRandomFactura = random_string('numeric', 6);
        
        if ($this->request->getFileMultiple('facturas')) {
            $facturasGuardar = [];
            foreach($this->request->getFileMultiple('facturas') as $file)
            {   
               $nuevoNombres = $nombreRandomFactura . '-' . $file->getName();
               $file->move('./public/assets/facturas',$nuevoNombres);
               $facturasGuardar[] = $nuevoNombres;
            }
            $data = [
               'nombre_proyecto'=> $this->request->getVar('nombre_proyecto'),
               'id_empresa'=> $this->request->getVar('id_empresa'),
               'facturas' =>  implode(",",$facturasGuardar)
            ];
        
       }

       $proyectos->insert($data);
       }
 
    return $this->response->redirect( site_url('/projectList')); 

}
```

Adjunto vista del formulario:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="inputClientCompany">Imagen<small>(Elegir multiples imagenes con CTRL+click)</small>:</label><br>
   <input type="file" name='img[]' multiple="" class="form-control">
   <br>
   <small>Archivos permitidos: jpg,jpeg,png. || Tamaño máximo -> 1mb</small>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
   <label for="inputFileCompany">Facturas<small>(Elegir multiples PDFS con CTRL+click)</small>:</label><br>
   <input type="file" name='facturas[]' multiple="" class="form-control">
   <br>
  <small>Archivos permitidos: pdf. || Tamaño máximo -> 1mb</small>
 </div>
```

Como puedo hacer que se suban ambos contenidos depende de mis necesidades¿ Gracias!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba esto:

```php
public function guardar()
{
    helper(['text', 'form', 'url']);

    $proyectos = new ProyectosModel();
 
    $validacion = $this->validate([
        'nombre_proyecto' => 'required|min_length[3]',
        'id_empresa' => 'required'
    ]);

    $this->validator->reset();

    $validacionIMG = $this->validate([
        'img' => [
            'uploaded[img]',
            'mime_in[img,image/jpg,image/png,image/jpeg]',
            'max_size[img,1024]'
        ]
    ]); 

    $this->validator->reset();

    $validacionFacturas = $this->validate([
        'facturas' => [
            'uploaded[facturas]',
            'mime_in[facturas,application/pdf]',
            'max_size[facturas,4096]'
        ]
    ]);

    // calculamos $data
    $data = null;
    switch (true) {
        // faltan los inputs de texto
        case !$validacion:
            $session = session();
            $session->setFlashdata('mensaje', 'Por favor, revise la información');
            return redirect()->back()->withInput();
            break;

        // con texto, sin facturas y sin imágenes
        case $validacion !== null and !$validacionIMG and !$validacionFacturas:
            $data = [
                'nombre_proyecto'=> $this->request->getVar('nombre_proyecto'),
                'id_empresa'=> $this->request->getVar('id_empresa')
             ];
            break;

        // con texto, sin facturas y con imágenes
        case $validacion !== null and $validacionIMG !== null and !$validacionFacturas:
            $imagenes = $this->calc_imagenes();
            if ($imagenes !== false) {
                $data = [
                   'nombre_proyecto'=> $this->request->getVar('nombre_proyecto'),
                   'id_empresa'=> $this->request->getVar('id_empresa'),
                   'img' =>  implode(",", $imagenes)
                ];
            }
            break;

        // con texto, con facturas y sin imágenes
        case $validacion !== null and $validacionFacturas !== null and !$validacionIMG:
            $facturasGuardar = $this->calc_facturas();
            if ($facturasGuardar !== false) {
                $data = [
                   'nombre_proyecto'=> $this->request->getVar('nombre_proyecto'),
                   'id_empresa'=> $this->request->getVar('id_empresa'),
                   'facturas' =>  implode(",", $facturasGuardar)
                ];
            }
            break;

        // con texto, con facturas y con imágenes
        case $validacion !== null and $validacionFacturas !== null and $validacionIMG !== null:
            $facturasGuardar = $this->calc_facturas();
            $imagenes = $this->calc_imagenes();
            if ($imagenes !== false and $facturasGuardar !== false) {
                $data = [
                   'nombre_proyecto'=> $this->request->getVar('nombre_proyecto'),
                   'id_empresa'=> $this->request->getVar('id_empresa'),
                   'facturas' => implode(",", $facturasGuardar),
                   'img' => implode(",", $imagenes)
                ];
            }
            break;
    }

    // insertamos registro
    if (!is_null($data)) {
        $proyectos->insert($data);
    } else {
        // si $data no contiene datos después del switch
        $session = session();
        $session->setFlashdata('mensaje', '¡Algo ha ido mal! Avisad al administrador de la web');
        return redirect()->back()->withInput();
    }
}

// calcula y devuelve array de imagenes
private function calc_imagenes()
{
    $nombreRandom = random_string('numeric', 6);

    if ($this->request->getFileMultiple('img')) {
        $imagenes = [];
        foreach ($this->request->getFileMultiple('img') as $file) {   
            $nuevoNombre = $nombreRandom . '-' . $file->getName();
            $file->move('./public/assets/img', $nuevoNombre);
            $imagenes[] = $nuevoNombre;
        }
        return $imagenes;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

// calcula y devuelve array de facturas
private function calc_facturas()
{
    $nombreRandomFactura = random_string('numeric', 6);

    if ($this->request->getFileMultiple('facturas')) {
        $facturasGuardar = [];
        foreach ($this->request->getFileMultiple('facturas') as $file) {   
            $nuevoNombres = $nombreRandomFactura . '-' . $file->getName();
            $file->move('./public/assets/facturas', $nuevoNombres);
            $facturasGuardar[] = $nuevoNombres;
        }
        return $facturasGuardar;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Como ves, he reescrito practicamente tu código cambiando estas cosas básicas:

1. En lugar de tanto `elseif` mi preferencia personal es usar [switch()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/control-structures.switch.php) con un operador booleano, en este caso `true` y en cada `case` poner la condición a cumplir.  Como digo es una preferencia personal, pero me sirve para leer mejor mi código.
2. En tu código te faltaba la condición de que se cumplieran ambos casos, es decir, que hubiera facturas e imágenes, y la he incluido dentro del *switch*, en el último **case**
3. Para no repetir código he creado dos nuevos métodos privados, **calc_imagenes()** y **calc_facturas()**, que simplemente crean los arrays de las imágenes y facturas, o en caso de no poder hacerlo devuelven el valor booleano de **false**
4. He quitado la línea del `$proyectos->insert($data);` fuera del **switch** y de cada **case**, el cual ahora tan solo calcula el valor de $data, y lo he puesto en un condicional para que o bien haga la inserción si $data ha sido rellenado o bien muestre un mensaje de aviso conforme algo ha ido mal:

```
    // insertamos registro
    if (!is_null($data)) {
        $proyectos->insert($data);
    } else {
        // si $data no contiene datos después del switch
        $session = session();
        $session->setFlashdata('mensaje', '¡Algo ha ido mal! Avisad al administrador de la web');
        return redirect()->back()->withInput();
    }
```

5. He tenido que agregar esta línea después del primer uso de `$this->validate` justo antes de cada uno de sus siguientes usos:

```
    $this->validator->reset();
```

porque codeIgniter exige su uso cuando se pasan varios arrays al método validate(), tal como reza la cabecera del código del método reset() en CI4, en system/Validation/Validation.php:

```
    /**
     * Resets the class to a blank slate. Should be called whenever
     * you need to process more than one array.
     */
    public function reset(): ValidationInterface
```

Comment: Cuando quiero insertar un pdf o varios en facturas y no pongo imagenes no se registra nada y aparece como vacio, pero es lo que no me entra en la cabeza porque. Por lo demas funciona perfecto todo y es muchisimo mas optimo! muchas gracias por tu ayuda no sabes como la valoro.

Comment: ¿Y no te sale el mensaje de error cuando eso sucede?  Ese de "Algo ha ido mal!"

Comment: no ,no aparece, simplemente inserta los datos de texto en la base de datos y se salta los archivos de las facturas y aparece la vista sin archivos.

Comment: vale,  ¿que tipo de campo es "facturas" en la base de datos?  ¿el mismo que img?

Comment: Haz una prueba, para ver si encontramos el punto donde no funciona... donde esta esto: `$facturasGuardar = [];` pon esto `$facturasGuardar = ["prueba"];` y vuelve a insertar datos con facturas y sin imágenes, a ver si al menos mete esa palabra

Comment: Otra cosa, acabo de actualizar mi respuesta, pero es un cambio que no tenia nada que ver.  Antes ponia `$break;` al final del ultimo `case` y tenia que ser sin la $, o sea, `break;`.  Funcionaba igual, solo que mejor arreglarlo.

Comment: Acabo de arreglar otro error tipográfico, heredado de tu código, y este quizás si que era el que estropeaba todo.  Busca en las lineas de los **case** esto: `!=` y modifícalo por esto: `!==` (ojo que ya hay algunos bien puestos, pero otros no), y luego vuelve a probar, creo que es eso tu problema inicial (aparte que no contemplabas el ultimo case, es decir, la subida simultanea de facturas e imagenes a la vez)

Comment: He arreglado todos los errores que comentabas y he probado pero no ha funcionado, también he probado a colocar en la funcion calc_facturas()       $facturasGuardar = ["prueba"];   pero no ha introducido nada.

Comment: En cuanto al tipo de campo de facturas es  varchar(100) utf8mb4_general_ci   exactamente igual que imagenes, de ehcho es extraño porque si insertamos imagenes y facturas si mete ambos valores en la base de datos.

Comment: Pues vamos a saco, a ver si lo encontramos.  En cada **case** coge la linea comentada de arriba y la pones abajo con un echo, es decir, si arriba del case pone `// con texto, sin facturas y sin imágenes`  creas una nueva linea debajo que ponga `echo "// con texto, sin facturas y sin imágenes";`  y así con todos, porque mucho me temo que el problema está en el $this->validate ahora, que no controlo porque no se lo que hace ni devuelve realmente, y quiero ver en que **case** se cree que está al subir archivos solamente

Comment: he hecho una prueba, he colocar que de nombre guardara una variable $prueba = "con texto, con facturas y sin imágenes";
                    $data = [
                       'nombre_proyecto'=>  $prueba ,
                       'id_empresa'=> $this->request->getVar('id_empresa'),
                       'facturas' =>  implode(",", $facturasGuardar)
                    ];     la he puesto tanto con solo imagenes como con solo facturas, si guardo imagenes accede y coloca su nombre de variable pero con facturas esto no ocurre, es decir no accede nunca a ese case

Comment: validacion digamos que comprueba los valores introducidos es decir, si el pdf es correcto, si el archivo pdf cumple con los valores que se indican. es  decir es de tipo pdf, tiene un tamaño maximo de X , etc. imagino que es un booleano, ya que si no es correcto no valida los campos introducidos.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137124/discussion-between-sara11-and-masterguru).